# Parallelize double sum in C with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I have this function Sum() in C that I would like to parallelize , using MPI :

```
double Sum(double* x, double* y, int n)
{
    double V = 0.0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
                V += F(x[i], y[j]);
        }
    }

    return V;
}
```

where `F(x[i],y[j])` is just a function that calculates something like the difference between the two elements or a similar binary operation.

Now I thought that I could  separate the sum on the various processors `p`using `MPI_Scatter()` to generate a local vecotr and then use `MPI_Reduce()` to bing the local sums togheter, unfortunately it seems that I am unable to do it. This was my solution but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double Parallel_Sum(double (*)(double, double), double*, double*, int, int);
double F(double, double);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int my_rank, p;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    int n = 10;
    double *y = calloc(n, sizeof(double)), *x = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    /*just for trial*/
    y[5] = 1;
    x[5] = 1;
    double* local_x = calloc(n / p, sizeof(double));
    MPI_Scatter(x, n / p, MPI_DOUBLE, local_x, n / p, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double local_S, S = 0.0;
    local_S = Parallel_Sum(F, local_x, y, n, p);

    MPI_Reduce(&local_S, &S, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (my_rank == 0)
    {
        printf("%lf\n", S);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

double F(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
double Parallel_Sum(double (*OP)(double, double), double* local_x, double* y, int n, int p)
{
    double local_V = 0.0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n / p; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
                local_V += OP(local_x[i], y[j]);
        }
    }

    return local_V;
}
```

In this example, the sum should be 0, since the vectors are all zero except for `y[5] = 1; x[5] = 1;` unfortunately for `p > 1` it never is zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *it doesn't seem to work*? Please be specific and also provide a minimal and verifiable code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited the question

Comment: `if (i != j)` in the innermost loop should be `if ((n/p) * my_rank + i != j)`, otherwise you are comparing a local index to a global one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double Parallel_Sum(double (*OP)(double,double),double* local_x,double* y,int n,int p, int rank){

    double local_V = 0.0;
    int i,j;

    for(i = rank*n/p;i<(rank+1)*n/p;i++){ // <-- changed
        for(j = 0;j<n;j++){    

            if(i != j)
                local_V += OP(local_x[i-rank*n/p],y[j]); // <-- changed                 
        }
    }

    return local_V;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please expand a little on why this works?

Comment: Regarding for loop, suppose that you ran with single processor. Then `0<i<10`. But when `np=2`, for each processor, you had `0=<i<5` which was true only for the first processor. For the second processor it should be `5=<i<10`.

Answer (score 1):

While the indexing in `local_x` is fine, the check for `i != j` is not. You must consider that `i` covers different parts of the global array, e.g. like that:

```
double Parallel_Sum(double (*OP)(double, double), double* local_x, double* y, int n, int p, int rank)
{
    double local_V = 0.0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n / p; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if ((i + rank * (n / p)) != j)
                local_V += OP(local_x[i], y[j]);
        }
    }

    return local_V;
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not work for number of processors greater than two.

Comment: I fixed the offset calculation.

Comment: Can you please be specific? Obviously I do assume that `n` is divisible by `p` as all of the remaining code does.

Comment: Sorry, silly by me. Since my answer (coincidentally) worked even for odd number of processors, it made me to think that your one is wrong.